'iostream' file not found clang(pp_file_not_found) errror
I've installed vscodium on my windows 10 pc. I've installed vscodium on my laptop before which is ubuntu linux so I assumed the process was straight forward. the problem I find is one of the extension's Clangd doesn't recognize my header file specifically <iostream> but also almost every c++ is not recognized. is there a way to change the extension itself to redirect the path where my header files are located?
I did some research and the files I seem to be lacking a compile_commands.json, compile_flags.txt, and other flags.txt. I did read the Clangd details tab that I need cmake to generate a compile_commands.json file. If so then how do I generate a compile_commands.json file with cmake? is there a another alternative method to change Clangd's directory
Code:
#include <iostream> //--- error message displayed here
                        ('iostream' file not found')

using namespace std; //--- error message displayed here
                        (ext_using_undefined_std)

int main(){


        cout << "Here I am.";  //--- error message
                                ("Use of undeclared identifier 'cout')

    return 0;
}


Output: 
[Done] exited with code=0 in 1.583 seconds

[Running] cd "c:\Users\wacom4\Documents\Program Folder\" && g++ ProgramTest.cpp -o ProgramTest && "c:\Users\wacom4\Documents\Program Folder\"ProgramTest
here I am.
[Done] exited with code=0 in 1.565 seconds

problems:
Problems 3

'iostream' file not found

[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/wacom4/Documents/Program Folder/ProgramTest.cpp",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#3",
    "code": "undeclared_var_use",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Use of undeclared identifier 'cout'",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 8,
    "startColumn": 5,
    "endLineNumber": 8,
    "endColumn": 9
}]


[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/wacom4/Documents/Program Folder/ProgramTest.cpp",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#3",
    "code": "ext_using_undefined_std",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Using directive refers to implicitly-defined namespace 'std'",
    "source": "clang",
    "startLineNumber": 3,
    "startColumn": 17,
    "endLineNumber": 3,
    "endColumn": 20
}]

and the c_cpp_properties.json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\10.3.0\\include",
        "C:\\Program Files\\CodeBlocks\\minGW\\include\\c++\\14.1.0"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/gcc.exe",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "compilerArgs": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}


Clang on Windows is not self-sufficient, it has to be used in combination with MSVC or MinGW and will use the standard library from the respective compiler. By default it will search for MSVC, and your error means it didn't find it. My recommendation would be to uninstall your MinGW and Clang (including Clangd), and reinstall them from MSYS2. Their version of Clang (as opposed to the offical one) will use their MinGW libs by default as opposed to looking for MSVC ones.

Alternatively you could keep the official Clang if you added --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 (to compiler flags passed to Clangd) to make it use MinGW libs. Or alternatively you could install VS and let Clang use VS libs. Also you don't need c_cpp_properties.json at all, because that's for the Microsoft's C/C++ extension while you're using Clangd. Also the contents of that file are sus, because you're mixing two MinGW versions: the one from CB and TDM-GCC.

Sounds like a duplicate of this: using Clang in windows 10 for C/C++
